# VC++ class objects with a VARIANT member have strange behavior

Tags: c++, windows, class, visual-c++, variant

I have a class defined below:

```
class CVariable  
{
   public:
     CVariable(CString strData, int nNum);
     CVariable(BSTR bsData);
     ~CVariable();
   public:
     VARIANT GetVariant(){return m_bsVa;};
   private:
     VARIANT m_bsVa;
   VARIANT m_nVa;
};
```

And implements are:

```
CVariable::CVariable(CString strData, int nNum)
{
  VariantInit(&m_bsVa);
  BSTR bsData = ::SysAllocString(strData);
  m_bsVa.vt = VT_BSTR;
  m_bsVa.bstrVal = bsData;
  ::SysFreeString(bsData);

  VariantInit(&m_nVa);
  m_nVa.vt = VT_I2;
  m_nVa.lVal = nNum;
}

CVariable::CVariable(BSTR bsData) {
  m_bsVa.vt = VT_BSTR;
  m_bsVa.bstrVal = bsData;
}

CVariable::~CVariable()
{
  VariantClear(&m_bsVa);
  VariantClear(&m_nVa);
}
```

When I try to construct two instances using constructor `CVariable(CString,int)`, 
class member *m_bsVa*s always have the same value,while *m_nVa*s are different.The result is below:
[image]

As you see, *v1* and *v2* have the same m_bsVa but different m_nVa, while using constructor `CVariable(BSTR)` leads to the right result. I've no idea why this can happen? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several problems with your code.

1. the `CVariable(CString, int)` constructor allocates a `BSTR` for `m_bsVa`, but then frees the `BSTR` immediately, leaving `m_bsVa` pointing at invalid memory, and allowing the next `CVariable` instance to potentially reuse the same memory address for its allocated `BSTR`.  You need to leave the `BSTR` allocated until you are done using `m_bsVa` (or at least until you want to assign a new value to it).  `VariantClear()` will free the `BSTR` for you.
2. the `CVariable(BSTR)` constructor is not initializing `m_nVa` at all, which will cause problems for subsequent operations on it, including `VariantClear()`.  Also, the constructor is taking ownership of the caller's `BSTR`.  That may or may not be OK, depending on how you use this constructor.  If the caller is not expecting you to take ownership, then you need to make a copy of the `BSTR` using `SysAllocString/Len()`.
3. `VARIANT` is not trivially copyable.  You need to use the `VariantCopy()` function to copy data from one `VARIANT` to another.  That means your `CVariable` class needs to implement a copy constructor and copy assignment operator.  Which you need to do anyway so your class conforms to the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).
4. `GetVariant()` is returning `m_bsVa` as-is, so the compiler will simply copy the values of `m_bsVa`'s fields as-is into the caller's receiving `VARIANT`.  Since `BSTR` is a pointer, the caller will have *direct access* to the original `BSTR` inside of your class.  That may or may not be OK, depending on how you use `GetVariant()`.  In the current implementation, any access to the returned `BSTR` should be treated as read-only - the caller *must not* call `SysFreeString()` on it, and must expect any change to the `CVariable` object *may* invalidate the `BSTR`.  If that does not suit your needs, then `GetVariant()` should return a new `VARIANT` that has copied the data via `VariantCopy()`, and then the caller can call `VariantClear()` when done using the returned `VARIANT`.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
class CVariable  
{
public:
    CVariable(const CString &strData, int nNum);
    CVariable(BSTR bsData);
    CVariable(const CVariable &src);
    ~CVariable();

    VARIANT GetVariant() const;

    CVariable& operator=(const CVariable &src);
    CVariable& operator=(BSTR src);

private:
    VARIANT m_bsVa;
    VARIANT m_nVa;
};
```

```
CVariable::CVariable(const CString &strData, int nNum)
{
    ::VariantInit(&m_bsVa);
    m_bsVa.vt = VT_BSTR;
    m_bsVa.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(strData);

    ::VariantInit(&m_nVa);
    m_nVa.vt = VT_I2;
    m_nVa.lVal = nNum;
}

CVariable::CVariable(BSTR bsData)
{
    ::VariantInit(&m_bsVa);
    m_bsVa.vt = VT_BSTR;
    m_bsVa.bstrVal = bsData;
    /* or this, if needed:
    m_bsVa.bstrVal = ::SysAllocStringLen(bsData, ::SysStringLen(bsData));
    */

    ::VariantInit(&m_nVa);
}

CVariable::~CVariable()
{
    ::VariantClear(&m_bsVa);
    ::VariantClear(&m_nVa);
}

VARIANT CVariable::GetVariant() const
{
    return m_bsVa;
    /* or this, if needed:
    VARIANT result;
    ::VariantInit(&result);
    ::VariantCopy(&result, &m_bsVa);
    return result;
    */
}

CVariable& CVariable::operator=(const CVariable &src)
{
    if (&src != this)
    {
        ::VariantClear(&m_bsVa);
        ::VariantCopy(&m_bsVa, &src.m_bsVa);

        ::VariantClear(&m_nVa);
        ::VariantCopy(&m_nVa, &src.m_nVa);
    }

    return *this;
}

CVariable& CVariable::operator=(BSTR src)
{
    ::VariantClear(&m_bsVa);
    m_bsVa.vt = VT_BSTR;
    m_bsVa.bstrVal = src;
    /* or this, if needed:
    m_bsVa.bstrVal = ::SysAllocStringLen(src, ::SysStringLen(src));
    */

    ::VariantClear(&m_nVa);

    return *this;
}
```

If you use the [`variant_t`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x295h94e.aspx) class instead of `VARIANT` directly, you can greatly simplify the code while still addressing all of the points mentioned above:

```
class CVariable  
{
public:
    CVariable(const CString &strData, int nNum);
    CVariable(BSTR bsData);

    variant_t GetVariant() const;

private:
    variant_t m_bsVa;
    variant_t m_nVa;
};
```

```
CVariable::CVariable(const CString &strData, int nNum)
    : m_bsVa(strData), m_nVa(nNum)
{
}

CVariable::CVariable(BSTR bsData)
    : m_bsVa(bsData)
{
}

variant_t CVariable::GetVariant() const
{
    return m_bsVa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this constructor :

```
CVariable::CVariable(BSTR bsData) {
  m_bsVa.vt = VT_BSTR;
  m_bsVa.bstrVal = bsData;
}
```

You are leaving `m_nVa` uninitialized - it gets some random value. It shall look like this instead:

```
CVariable::CVariable(BSTR bsData) {
  VariantInit(&m_bsVa);
  m_bsVa.vt = VT_BSTR;
  m_bsVa.bstrVal = bsData;

  VariantInit(&m_nVa);
}
```

And in this constructor:

```
CVariable::CVariable(CString strData, int nNum)
{
  VariantInit(&m_bsVa);
  BSTR bsData = ::SysAllocString(strData);
  m_bsVa.vt = VT_BSTR;
  m_bsVa.bstrVal = bsData;
  ::SysFreeString(bsData);

  VariantInit(&m_nVa);
  m_nVa.vt = VT_I2;
  m_nVa.lVal = nNum;
}
```

Do not call `::SysFreeString(bsData);` as `bsData` is owned by `m_bsVa`.
`SysFreeString()` frees the memory and the next `SysAllocString()` call may create a new `BSTR` string at the same memory address.

Instead of using *naked* VARIANTs, I'd suggest you use the [`_variant_t` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x295h94e.aspx) instead. In this case, you will not need to worry about `VariantInit()`/`VariantClear()` at all, as it implements ownership policies in C++ style for you.

Comment: I forgot it.However what I wanna know is why using `CVariable(CString, int)` leads to same m_bsVa values and different m_nVa values.

Comment: I've updated my answer, remove `::SysFreeString(bsData);` from the ctor. I strongly suggest to use `_variant_t` instead, otherwise you shall understand ownership policies of VARIANT very well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a convenient C++ RAII wrapper around raw C VARIANTs, like CComVariant from ATL.

This will simplify your code, as CComVariant will properly initialize its wrapped raw VARIANT, and clean it up as well.

You can replace your VARIANT data members with safer CComVariant wrappers:

```
CComVariant m_bsVa;
CComVariant m_nVa;
```

Then you can initialize them in constructors like this:

```
CVariable::CVariable(const CString& strData, int nNum)
    : m_bsVa(strData), m_nVa(nNum)
{}

CVariable::CVariable(BSTR bsData)
    : m_bsVa(bsData)
{}
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly define a destructor, as in this case CComVariant's destructor will properly cleanup data members.

Your getter could be implemented like this:

```
const CComVariant& CVariable::GetVariant() const
{
    return m_bsVa;
}
```